# LINQ query for getting LatestDate for Id

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following CompletedForms table.

```
Id  FilledBy    DateCompleted
1   23          2015-03-27 12:00:13.807
2   24          2015-03-27 12:00:20.550
3   23          2015-03-27 13:32:19.000
4   23          2015-03-27 14:43:09.767
6   29          2015-03-30 08:54:23.533
```

I want to select the latest DateCompleted for each id in FilledBy.

How do I do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 1):

```
CompletedForms.GroupBy(x=>x.FilledBy)
              .Select(x=>new {FileldBy=x.Key, LastCompletedDate = x.Max(y=>y.DateCompleted))
```